# django-rest-framework: aserializer.data returns ReturnDict and OrderedDict instead of dict object

Tags: serialization, django-rest-framework

I have written a model serializer class for a model. When I test to see if it serializes properly I get following error.

`AssertionError: ReturnDict([(u'id', 1), ('apple', OrderedDict([(u'id', 1), ('data', u'this is a apple data.')])) ...`

I tried converting it to dict wrapping aserializer.data to dict function like

`dict(aserializer.data)`

Then I get following error.

`AssertionError: {'status': False, 'http': OrderedDict([(u'id', 1), ...`

How to get dictionary data from a serializer.